# Add value to current row of a dataframe with 'datetime' index, if date is between current and previous index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have tow dataframes `stockData` and `EPSdata` as below.
`stockData` will be

```
            Close 
Date
2018-12-31  157.066376
2018-09-30  223.994431
2018-06-30  183.036682
2018-03-31  165.263504
2017-12-31  166.014908
2017-09-30  150.650375
2017-06-30  140.227097
2017-03-31  139.301605
2016-12-31  111.821404
2016-09-30  108.589523
2016-06-30  91.333252
2016-03-31  103.495514
2015-12-31  99.414101
2015-09-30  103.730179
......
```

and `EPSData` will be

```
           Surprise_perc
Date
2018-11-01          4.30
2018-07-31          7.83
2018-05-01          1.49
2018-02-01          1.83
2017-11-02         10.70
2017-08-01          6.37
2017-05-02          3.96
2017-01-31          4.35
2016-10-25          0.60
2016-07-26          2.16
.......
```

how can i combine both these dataframes ?
The first datapoint in `EPSData`," `2018-11-01  4.30`"  shoud be added to Q4 in `stockData` ie, to the datapoint  "`2018-12-31   157.066376`".
The output should look like

```
            Close       Surprise_perc
Date
2018-12-31  157.066376  4.30
2018-09-30  223.994431  7.83
2018-06-30  183.036682  1.49
2018-03-31  165.263504  1.83
2017-12-31  166.014908  10.70
2017-09-30  150.650375  6.37
2017-06-30  140.227097  3.96
2017-03-31  139.301605  4.35
2016-12-31  111.821404  0.60
2016-09-30  108.589523  2.16
.....
```

here both dataframes are indexed on dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = (pd.merge_asof(stockData.sort_index(), 
                    EPSData.sort_index(), 
                    left_index=True, 
                    right_index=True)
        .sort_index(ascending=False))
print (df)
                 Close  Surprise_perc
Date                                 
2018-12-31  157.066376           4.30
2018-09-30  223.994431           7.83
2018-06-30  183.036682           1.49
2018-03-31  165.263504           1.83
2017-12-31  166.014908          10.70
2017-09-30  150.650375           6.37
2017-06-30  140.227097           3.96
2017-03-31  139.301605           4.35
2016-12-31  111.821404           0.60
2016-09-30  108.589523           2.16
2016-06-30   91.333252            NaN
2016-03-31  103.495514            NaN
2015-12-31   99.414101            NaN
2015-09-30  103.730179            NaN
```

Comment: @Shijith - Is possible create new question with this new problem?

Comment: @Shijith - But one idea is use a bit hack - `EPSData = EPSData.fillna('tmp')`, apply solution and last `df = df.repalce('tmp', np.nan)`

Comment: Thank you very much for a swift response and introducing me to merge_asof. This works well for me for most of the stocks. But i have a few stocks for which  'EPSData' data is missing for some quarters. so i have made a slight change and added a new parameter for tolerence (of 60 days), `tolerance=pd.Timedelta('60d')`.  edited code is :  `df = pd.merge_asof(a.sort_index(), EPS.sort_index(), left_index=True, right_index=True,tolerance=pd.Timedelta('60d')).sort_index(ascending=False)`. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @ jezrael, there is no 'NaN' values also, data is like Q1 and then Q4, no columns in between. May be i have to find a better data source. Thank you.

Comment: `tolerance=pd.Timedelta('90d')` works well for all stocks, the problem with 60 is that some companies will report EPS within a month.